# how to turn a number from the unit form into an integer in prolog?

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I have his code in prolog:

```
int2term(0,0).
int2term(N,s(T)) :- N>0, M is N-1, int2term(M,T).
int2term(N,p(T)) :- N<0, M is N+1, int2term(M,T).
```

that shows a number from this form s(s(0)) to this form 2 .
I tried to make the reversed version specically 2 -> s(s(0)) using this but nothing :

```
term2int(0,0).
term2int(N,T) :- N>0, M is N-1, term2int(M,s(T)).
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: A _suggestion_ would be first of all to tell us what you mean by "nothing" (show the result you are getting and what you actually expect).
Also, you are not treating `p` at all, only `s`.

Comment: when i try term2int(s(s(0)),T). i got this:
| ?- term2int(s(s(0)),T).
uncaught exception: error(type_error(evaluable,s/1),(>)/2)

Comment: Your second `term2int` clause seems to assume that the first argument `N` is an integer (you have `N > 0, M is N-1,`. But you are passing it `s(s(0))`, so prolog is attempting `s(s(0)) > 0` which fails since `>` doesn't work on that form of expression. The meaning of your parameters seems a little confused since you called it with a "term" as the first argument, but the recursive call uses a "term" for the second argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this but it should work:

```
term2int(0,0).

term2int(s(T),N) :- term2int(T,N1), N is N1+1.

term2int(p(T),N) :- term2int(T,N1), N is N1-1.
```

No need to check if > 0 or otherwise, just use `s` and `p` for that case. Also `N` works as a counter.

Comment: For bonus points, you should use `var/1` and see if you can merge term2int and int2term into a single predicate that "does the right thing" depending on how it is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different version which is tail recursive and avoids some of the infinite recursion cases (e.g., try `term2int(T, 2).` and press `;` after the first solution):

```
term2int(0, 0).
term2int(s(X), Y) :-
    term2int(s(X), 0, Y).
term2int(p(X), Y) :-
    term2int(p(X), 0, Y).

term2int(0, Y, Y) :- !.
term2int(s(X), A, Y) :-
    (integer(Y) -> Y > 0 ; true),
    A1 is A+1,
    term2int(X, A1, Y).
term2int(p(X), A, Y) :-
    (integer(Y) -> Y < 0 ; true),
    A1 is A-1,
    term2int(X, A1, Y).
```